# Specify a range (upper and lower bound) for a variable in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to specify bounds for a float variable in Python? For example, when I import data, I would like to either check if it within certain range such that `min <= variable <=max`. Further, if possible, I would like assign a specific value to such variable if the imported value is outside of these bounds (or even missing).

I can perhaps do the first part if the variable was a float.

```
def var_check(x,lower_bound=3,upper_bound=30):
    rng = range(lower_bound,upper_bound+1)
    if x not in rng:
        return (upper_bound-lower_bound)/2
    else:
        return x
```

`x = var_check(5)` returns 5, while `x = var_check(50)` returns 13.

Any ideas on how to do this for a float variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do almost exactly what you wrote in your question:

```
def var_check(x, lower_bound=3, upper_bound=30):
    if lower_bound <= x <= upper_bound:
        return x
    else:
        return (upper_bound - lower_bound) / 2
```

You should do the same with integers, by the way, at least in Python 2. In Python 3 (or with `xrange` in Python 2), it doesn't matter so much.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could look like this:

```
def var_check(x, lower_bound=3, upper_bound=30):
    if x >= lower_bound and x <= upper_bound:
        return x
    return (upper_bound-lower_bound)/2

print(var_check(2.5))
print(var_check(15.5))
print(var_check(33.5))
```

Output

```
13.5
15.5
13.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class and override its [`__float__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)

```
class MyFloat:
   def __init__(self, num, upper=20, lower=10):
       self.num = num
       self.upper = upper
       self.lower = lower

   def __float__(self):
       if self.lower <= self.num <= self.upper:
           return float(self.num)
       else:
           return (self.upper - self.lower) / 2
```

Then while importing your data you can do

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,10,11,12,21,22,23]
>>> [float(MyFloat(d)) for d in data]
>>> [5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: This seems like an interesting but a bit complicated solution. Nonetheless, I get the `TypeError: __float__ returned non-float (type int)` message.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data which throws this error?

Comment: I just ran the example that you included, and I was getting that TypeError, which I mentioned earlier. After the edit that you provided, the example works now, thanks!